# how to create a form with three text input fields with only one submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to create an html form that would accept 3 different types of query request, using 3 text fields and one submit button. when the person enters data into one of the field and click the submit button , it will query the database based on the input. I can do it with one text box, but I can't figure out how to do 3 text box. Also the person can only choose only choose to query one text field at a time.

Field 1 is student_id field 2 is last_name field 3 is exam_date.

Person can enter student_id, and only student_id, or last_name and only last name, or examDate and only exam date.

One of the problems I'm having is how to pass 3 different types of data to pass through to the PHP and query in the select statement. It seems I would have to create 3 different select query statements, but how do I create a code to recognize which query to run?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
   <div id="form_wrap"><!-- start form wrap -->
     <div id="form_header">
       </div>
         <div id="form_body">
         <p>Search for a certification request (Enter one of the following):</p>
         <form action="search.php" method="post" name="information" id="information" 
        onsubmit="return(validate())">
        <div class="field"> 
            <label for = "Student_id"> Student ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for = "last_name"> Last Name:</label>     
            <input type="text" name="last" id="last" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for = "examDate"> Exam Date:</label>  
            <input type="text" name="date" id="mm/dd/yyyy"  /> 
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the php code

```
     <?php
require 'security.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// Otherwise we connect to our Database
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'corpmis_ddempsey');
//check connection
if($db->connect_errno) {
    die('sorry, we are having some problems');
    }else {
    echo 'connected';
}

$search = $_REQUEST['search'];
//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
if ($search == "")
{
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;
}
// We perform a bit of filtering
 //$search = strtoupper($search);
$search = strip_tags($search);
$search = trim ($search);

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
//$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE student_id LIKE '$search'");
/*

");
*/
//And we display the results
    if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE student_id LIKE '$search'" )){
        if($result->num_rows){
            while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $records[] = $row;
            }
        $result->free();
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>People</h3>
    <?php
    if(!count($records)) {
    echo 'No records';

    } else {

    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>student_id</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>Major</th>
                <th>Exam Name</th>
                <th>Taken class</th>
                <th>Prepare</th>
                <th>MeasureUp Key</th>
                <th>Exam Date</th>
                <th>Request Made On</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($records as $r){
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $r->student_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->first_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->last_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->email; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->major; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->examName?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->taken_class; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->prepare; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->MeasureUpKey; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->examDate; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->request_made; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }

                ?>

            </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you can use multiple columns on a where clause, just search it, `where col1 = 2 and col2 = whatever ...`

Comment: you can do id what you want to its easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can't. You can identify which input box has a value and create your query according to that. However, it is possible to fill multiple inputs and submit the form, so that won't work.
One option is to use a dropdown and let the user choose which input it wants to fill. For example:

```
<select name="type">
    <option value="student_id">Student ID</option>
    <option value="last_name">Last name</option>
    <option value="date">Exam date</option>
</select>
<input name="typeValue" value="" />
```

Now you know on which field the user wants to query. You can catch this with e.g.:

```
<?php
    //Note that you should add checks using e.g. isset()
    $value = $_POST['typeValue'];

    if($_POST['type'] == "student_id")
    {
        //Query with $value on student_id
    }
    elseif($_POST['type'] == "last_name")
    {
        //Query with $value on last_name
    }
    elseif($_POST['type'] == "date")
    {
        //Query with $value on date
    }
?>
```

Or if it's in the same table and the `option` values are the same as the column names in your table:

```
<?php
    //Note that you should add checks using e.g. isset()
    //Also note this is vulnerable for SQL injection, using prepared statements will solve that.
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE ".$_POST['type']." LIKE '%".$_POST['typeValue']."%'" );
?>
```

You also can fix this using Javascript. An option with javascript is to identify which input field is filled as last and create your query according to the last filled input field.

Comment: Thanks S.Pols I will try this, it looks like that will solve it. I will also put in code to prevent sql injections. By the way some suggested using AJax but I don't know that code yeah, but plan too learn it, just not there yet.

Comment: having problems.. when I test the code to see if it works its coming back with no result when I know it does exist.. here is the code i used based on what you suggested.. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: [code]                                                           
  $records = array();                                          $typeValue = $_REQUEST['typeValue'];                                  if ($typeValue == "")                                               echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;                                                            $typeValue = strip_tags($typeValue);
$typeValue = trim ($typeValue);                                                                                                                   [/code]

Comment: [code]                                                       if(!empty($_POST)) {
  if(isset($_POST['last_name'],$_POST['student_id'],$_POST['examDate']));{
    
    $last_name =   trim($_POST['last_name']);
    $student_id =   trim($_POST['student_id']);
    $examDate =   trim($_POST['examDate']);

    if(!empty($last_name) && !empty($student_id) && !empty($examDate)){                            [/code]

Comment: [code]                                                            if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE ".$_POST['type']." LIKE '%".$_POST['typeValue']."%'"  )){
    if($result->num_rows){
     while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
      $records[] = $row;
      }
    $result->free();
     }
 
    }
   }
  }
}                                                                        [/code]

Comment: Ok I will do that, but the admins of the blog always seem to have problems with me doing that.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to achieve this, but you can use ajax request here. Send ajax post request to your sql query page with user entered value as a post parameter.

On the query page, you can pass that post parameter into where clause of sql query. Then fill up the table on ajax success response.

Answer (score 0):

my html code

```
[code]

<!-- start javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[ */
   function check(){
    if(document.lastname.last.value == "" || document.lastname.last.value == null)
    {
        alert("no last name entered");
        return false;
    }
}
function checkdate() {
var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
if(!(date_regex.test(testDate)))
{
return false;
}

}

function fieldSwap(image){
 var sb = document.getElementById('sb');
 if(sb.value == ""){
  sb.style.background = "url(images/"+image+") no-repeat";
  }
}

function buttonSwap(image){
 var sb = document.getElementById('sb');
 sb.src = "images/"+image;
}
function validate(){
var x = document.information.search.value;
if (x.length<10 ||  x.length>10){
alert("student id is incorrect");
return false;
}
}

/*]]> */    
</script>
<!-- end javascript -->




</head>


<body>

<div id="form_wrap"><!-- start form wrap -->
     <div id="form_header">
     </div>
     <div id="form_body">
     <p>Search for a certification request (Enter one of the following):</p>
     <form action="search.php" method="POST" name="information" id="information" onsubmit="return(validate())">

       <div class="field">  
            <select name="type">
                <option value="student_id">Student ID</option>
                <option value="last_name">Last name</option>
                <option value="examdate">Exam date</option>
            </select>
            <input name="typeValue" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
     </form>
    </div>
</div>  

    </div><!-- end form wrap -->

    </body>
    </html>

[/code
```

php code.. only testing student_id query to see if I coded right, then will add select query for last name and exam date.

[code]

```
$records = array();

$typeValue = $_REQUEST['typeValue'];

echo $typeValue;
//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
if ($typeValue == "")
{
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;
}
// We perform a bit of filtering
//$typevalue = strtoupper($search);
$typeValue = strip_tags($typeValue);
$typeValue = trim ($typeValue);

     //Note that you should add checks using e.g. isset()
    $value = $_POST['typeValue'];

    if($_POST['type'] == "student_id")
    {
        //Query with $value on student_id

        if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE student_id LIKE '$typeValue'" )){
            if($result->num_rows){
                while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                }
            $result->free();
            }
        }
    }
    elseif($_POST['type'] == "last_name")
    {
        //Query with $value on last_name
    }
    elseif($_POST['type'] == "date")
    {
        //Query with $value on date
    }           


/*}*/ echo "value of $value" .$value;

//This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a     little     message explaining that
$anymatches=$result;
if ($anymatches == 0 )
{
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...<br><br>";
}

//And we remind them what they searched for
echo "<b>Results For:</b> " .$typeValue;
//}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Search Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Results</h3>
        <?php
        if(!count($records)) {
        echo 'No records';

        } else {

        ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>student_id</th>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <th>Major</th>
                    <th>Exam Name</th>
                    <th>Taken class</th>
                    <th>Prepare</th>
                    <th>MeasureUp Key</th>
                    <th>Exam Date</th>
                    <th>Request Made On</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach($records as $r){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $r->student_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->first_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->last_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->major; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->examName?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->taken_class; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->prepare; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->MeasureUpKey; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->examDate; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->request_made; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }

                    ?>

                </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</html>
```

[/code]

Comment: Thanks s.Pol I figured it out using what you gave me. now I have one other problem that I will starta new post on..so this post does not become irrelevant.